# Should I write rails tests with the def or test keyword?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, testing

This seems like a simple question but I can't find the answer anywhere.  I've noticed that in general, tests in a Ruby on Rails app can be written as:

```
  test "the truth" do
    assert true
  end
```

or

```
  def the_truth
    assert true
  end
```

It seems newer material writes tests the first way, but I can't seem to find a reason for this.  Is one favored over the other?  Is one more correct? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There has been a shift in recent years from short, abbreviated test names to longer, sentence-like test names. This is partly due to the popularity of RSpec and the concept that tests are specs and should be descriptive.

If you prefer descriptive test names, I highly recommend going with the `test` method. I find it to be more readable.

```
test "should not be able to login with invalid password" do
  #...
end

def_should_not_be_able_to_login_with_invalid_password
  #...
end
```

Also, because the description is a string it can contain any characters. With `def` you are limited in which characters you can use.

Comment: Is the `test` method part of Rspec or some other library?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the first method was implemented starting with Rails 2.2.
As far as I am aware, it simply improves readability of your code (as def can be any function while test is used only in test cases).
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

As Mike Trpcic suggests you should check out RSpec and Cucumber.  I'd like to add that you should also take a look at:

- Shoulda (http://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda/tree/master)
- Factory Girl (http://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/tree/master)

Shoulda is a macro framework for writing concise unit tests for your models/controllers, while the second is a replacement for fixtures.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest doing your testing with either [RSpec](http://rspec.info/) or [Cucumber](http://cukes.info/).  I use both to test all my applications.  RSpec is used to test the models and controllers, and Cucumber tests the Views (via the included [Webrat](http://github.com/brynary/webrat/tree/master) functionality).